# Problem when setting a value to a dropdown in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this strange problem in JQuery. I try to set a value to a dropdown dinamically, so I have this code:

```
$('#activity').val(idValue);
//or this way:
$('#activity').val("'"+idValue+"'");
```

but it does not work. However, if I'm setting the value "statically" then it works:

```
$('#activity').val('23');
```

So, why does not accept the value from the variable? Or what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have tried the code in jsfiddle and it does work. It seems that the problem was related to the JSON data i was parsing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the value of idValue in debug?

Comment: Are you sure that `idValue == 23`?

Comment: please show html and javascript code.

Comment: @VAShhh is 23, anyway, the values of idValue are identical with does of the option tag from the dropdown; I have checked

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ - to show the live example.

Comment: That _does_ work: [Here's proof](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/sMKCw/).  As Guarav requests, can you post the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get if you alert idValue?

Alternatively, I would also try [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$('#activity').attr('value',idValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

idValue may be a number type, try

```
$('#activity').val(idValue.toString());
```

Comment: toString converts a number object in a string, i don't think is the case here. Anyway, i have tried and... nothing.

Comment: please post a fiddle of your case so we can figure it out!